# kable's collapse_rows() and border

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

Please see the following kable:

```
df <- data.frame(
  C1 = 1:2, 
  C2 = c("a", "a"), 
  C3 = 3:4, 
  C4 = 5:6, 
  C5 = c("b", "b"), 
  row.names = c("Row 1", "Row 2")
  )

df %>% 
  kable() %>%
  add_header_above(c("", "Group 1" = 2, "", "Group 2" = 2), 
                   extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid green;") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = c(3, 6)) %>% 
  row_spec(0, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;") %>%
  row_spec(1, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid red;") %>%
  row_spec(2, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid blue;")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I have two problems:

- I would like to completely remove the line between Row 1 and Row 2.
- I would like to have the entire line below Row 2.

I added red and blue colors just to show what is happening.

After using `collapse_rows()`, `row_spec()` treats the bottom of columns C2 and C5 as belonging to row 1.

So when I edit `row_spec(1, ...)` (see red color), I end up editing lines in different rows.
Same with `row_spec(2, ...)` (see blue color), I cannot edit the lines of the columns with collapsed rows.

I tried to use `column_spec()`, but it is also not working well. For example,

`column_spec(3, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid brown;")`

adds a line to columns C2 and C3,

`column_spec(4, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid brown;")`

adds lines to different rows, and

`column_spec(5, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid brown;")`

gives an error instead of adding a line under C5.

I was expecting to have this:

[image]

I tried to use `border-bottom: none;` to get rid of the red line part, but the line remains visible.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Using a bit of trial and error, you can control the lines with extra row and column specs. It seems the `column_specs` only work if they are placed before the call to `collapse rows`.

PS I had to work with the development version of kableExtra: `devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")` as there seems to be an issue with `collapse_rows`: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/706

```
library(kableExtra)

  df |> 
  kable(fomat = "latex") |>
  add_header_above(c("", "Group 1" = 2, "", "Group 2" = 2), 
                   extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid green;") |>
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) |>
  column_spec(3, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;") |> 
  column_spec(6, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;") |> 
  collapse_rows(columns = c(3, 6)) |> 
  row_spec(0, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;") |> 
  row_spec(2, extra_css = "border-top: 1px solid white;") |>
  row_spec(2, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid;")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

I did not know about the order of the commands having such an effect... Noted.